# Access value in dynamic list of dict python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one list consist of different dict and I want to assign each dict using the first key of dict inside the list so that I can use that variable in future.

but the thing is the list of dict is dynamic the order of each dict inside main list is different so how can i assign to variable using key

```
    "api_responses": [{
        "ada_response": {
            "failed": true
        }
    }, {
        "link_response": {
            "faliureUrls": [],
            "numberChecked": 0,
            "numberOfFailed": 0
        }
    }, {
        "wp_response": {
            "version": "false"
        }
    }, {
        "tag_response": {
            "GTM": false,
            "analytics": true
        }
    }, {
        "drupal_response": {
            "version": "7.56"
        }
    }]
```

i have this and i want to assign variable to each dic using ada_response,link_response,wp_response,tag_response,        drupal_response keys.

and also this is not static  the order of the ada_response,link_response,wp_response,tag_response,        drupal_response keys may very .

i want like

```
ada_response = {
            "failed": true
        }
link_response =  {
            "faliureUrls": [],
            "numberChecked": 0,
            "numberOfFailed": 0
        }
```

and so on..

Comment: Update your post with your expected output based on your example so we can better understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: added the expected output @soueuls

Comment: @Kalariva_M you can use globals()[k]=v to create dynamic global vaiables. If you want do define local vaiables use locals() instead. But unless you are in a shell this is useless.

Comment: but how can i use global and local variables in my case ? @MegaIng

Comment: @Kalariya_M You can't. locals() and globals() should not be modified directly. You need to create a dictionary holding your dynamically allocated dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

This works, but you shouldn't do it:

```
for r in api_responses:
    for k,v in r.items():
        globals()[k]=v
```

Comment: can you explain your answer ?

Comment: Those dictionaries are supposed to be read-only, you can in fact overwrite them, nothing will prevent you. But the system might decide to over-overwrite them, thus, making them unreliable to store dynamic data.